# Can $X$ have compact connected components?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff, locally compact but non-compact topological space.
If the (Alexandroff) one-point compactification is connected, can $X$ have compact connected components?

Comment: Do you mean *all connected components are compact* $\;$ or $\;$ *there is a compact component* ?

Answer (score 3):

I think I proved the following

> **Lemma**
>
> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $C \subset X$ have a compact neighbourhood $K$. Then $C$ is a component of $X$ if and only if $C$ is a component of $K$.

in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/96743/3457).

For the present problem this implies a negative answer, since a compact set
in a locally compact Hausdorff space has a compact neighbourhood. Let $C$ be
a compact component of $X$, and let $K$ be some compact neighbourhood of $C$ in
$X$. Applying the lemma one way then shows that $C$ is a component of $K$, and
then applying it the other way shows that $C$ is a component of the
compactification, since $K$ remains a compact neighbourhood of $C$.

Comment: +1. That Lemma seems correct (after going through it) and it is quite powerful :) Thanks again for pointing out my mistake in my answer below.

Comment: @StefanHamcke: Thanks for confirming that. I wasn't too confident since hardly anyone else seemed to even have looked at it.

Answer (score -1):

Well, no. Assume $X=Y\sqcup C$, where $C$ is compact. Then the 1PC is $X\cup\{\infty\}$ with the topology: $U$ is open iff $U\subset X$ is open in the previous topology or $\infty\in U$ and $U^c$ is compact. Then $C = (U\cup\{\infty\})^c$ is compact, and thus $U\cup\{\infty\}$ is open. $C$ is also open (it was open in $X$). Thus the 1PC of $X$ is not connected.

Comment: Why can we assume that $X=Y\sqcup C$ ?

Comment: @Stefan: It certainly isn’t true in general for locally compact, non-compact Hausdorff spaces; just look at the Cantor set minus a point, for instance.

Comment: C can not be open in X

Comment: @iago Of course it can. It will also be closed, of course, but this doesn't exclude it from being open. Indeed, it is open by my definition of $X$ as a disjoint union.