# The boundary of a closed subset $A$ of a compact connected hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact connected hausdorff space. Let $A\subseteq X$ such that $A$ is closed and $A\neq\emptyset,X$. Let $C$ be a (connected) component of $A$. Is it true that $C\cap\partial A\neq\emptyset$?

Comment: Do you mean by component a subset?

Comment: @aGer: No, the OP means a [connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space).

Comment: I edited my answer. Sorry about the previous mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma 1:** Connected components of any topological space are always closed sets in that space.

**Proof:** let $D$ be a connected component of some arbitrary topological space $Y$. Since closures of connected sets are connected, it follows that $\overline{D}$ is a connected set intersecting $D$. By definition of connected component, any connected set intersecting $D$ is contained in $D$, so it follows that $\overline{D} \subseteq D$. Thus $\overline{D}=D$, so $D$ is closed). $\Box$

**Lemma 2:** Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, and let $U \subset X$ be open. If $C$ is a compact connected component of $U$, then $C$ is a connected component of $X$.

**Proof:** (This is the hardest part.) Apply the second lemma in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22032/if-c-is-a-component-of-y-and-a-component-of-z-is-it-a-component-of-y-cup/96743#96743), with $Y=U$ and $Z=C\cup(X \backslash U)$. $\Box$

Returning to the original question, we see by Lemma $1$ that $C$ is a closed (hence compact) subset of $X$.

Assume for contradiction that $C \cap \partial A = \emptyset$. Since $C \subset A$, this means that $C$ and $\overline{X \backslash A}$ are disjoint closed subsets of the normal space $X$. Thus there exist disjoint open sets $U,V$ such that $C \subset U$ and $\overline{X \backslash A} \subset V$. Since $C$ is a connected component of $A$ and since $U \subset A$, it follows that $C$ is a connected component of $U$. By Lemma $2$, we see that $C$ is also a connected component of $X$. By connectedness of $X$ this implies that $C=X$ or $C=\emptyset$, contradiction.

Comment: To prove that second lemma, he uses the first lemma, but I'm having trouble seeing why $C\cap B=\emptyset$ in the if part of that first lemma. In that lemma, the first one, $K$ is a compact subset of $X$, which is Hausdorff, and $B$ is $\partial K$ in $X$. In my question $X$ is Hausdorff, and compact and connected. If my $X$ is Hausdorff too,  $A$ is compact too  (because $A$ is closed in a compact) and my $C$ is a component of $A$, why there, in the if part of the first lemma, $C\cap\partial A=\emptyset$, but you prove that $C\cap\partial A\neq\emptyset$. What is going on?!

Comment: @QuiqueRuiz: The reason that $C \cap B = \emptyset$ is that $C$ has an open neighborhood (namely, the interior of $K$) which does not intersect $X \backslash K$.

Comment: Duh for me. I missed that. Thanks.