# Are the complements of two homeomorphic compact, connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $A,B$ are subsets of $\Bbb{R}^2$. If $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic and $A$ and $B$ are compact and connected, are their complements homeomorphic?

Comment: The complement is a disjoint union of open sets where all but the unbounded one are simply connected, i.e., homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$, and the unbounded one is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{O\}$.
Hence any differences can only come from different *number* of components.

Comment: It is interesting that this clearly fails in $\Bbb R^3$. Take a circle and a non-trivial knot.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen And it's obvious that the number of components must be the same. Where as always "obvious" means I have no idea how to prove it... ?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich There's a reason why I suddenly decided to move the txt from the answer edit to the comment edit :)

Comment: We can prove the very special case when $A$ and $B$ are topological manifolds with boundaries. A homeomorphism $\varphi:A\to B$ always restricts to a homeomorphism $\varphi:\partial A\to\partial B$ so they have the same number of components and @HagenvonEitzen arguments applies.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Alexander daulity finishes your argument. I don't know how to write the upside-down-hat so I'm just going to write $\hat H$. $\hat H^0(X) = \prod_{qC(X)} \mathbb Z$, where the product is taken over the number of quasicomponents of $X$. Quasicomponents of a manifold are the same as components. $\prod_{A} \mathbb Z \cong \prod_{B} \mathbb Z$ if and only if $A$ is in bijection with $B$. We're done.

Comment: Just use Alexander duality to prove that for two homeomorphic compacts A, B, all homology groups of $R^2-A, R^2-B$ are isomorphic to each other. In particular, the numbers of complementary components are the same. Then use the classification of open surfaces to conclude that the complements are homeomorphic.

Comment: @studiosus: Welcome back!

Comment: tnx guys...  ;-)

Comment: @MikeMiller By the way, $\check H$ = `\check H`

Comment: @Spenser: Morally the point is that for noncompact surfaces, $H_1$ determines $\pi_1$, and $\pi_1$ nearly determines the surface. For 3-manifolds neither of these are true.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Let's work in the sphere $S^2$ for convenience. Let $A$ be a connected compact proper subset of $S^2$. Its complement is an open (noncompact without boundary) surface $M'$; its complement in $\mathbb R^2$ is $M' - \{\infty\}$. This is a disjoint union of connected noncompact surfaces without boundary; each of these must have free fundamental group.

For manifolds $M$, the Cech cohomology $\check H^*(M)$ is [isomorphic to the singular cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cech_cohomology#Relation_to_other_cohomology_theories) $H^*(M)$. By [Alexander duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality), and the fact that $\check H_0(A) = 0$ (everything is happening in the reduced world!), we see that $H^1(M') = 0$. (The $0$th Cech homology more precisely counts quasicomponents, but for compact Hausdorff spaces, [quasicomponents are the same as components](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600904/98602).) Because for a disjoint union $H^1(X \sqcup Y) \cong H^1(X) \times H^1(Y)$, we see that every component of $M'$ is simply connected. By the uniformization theorem, each simply connected component is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$. Now delete the point at infinity; this makes one of your copies of $\mathbb R^2$ into an annulus $S^1 \times (-1,1)$.

So your $M$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \times (-1,1) \sqcup \kappa \mathbb R^2$, where by $\kappa \mathbb R^2$ I mean the disjoint union of $\kappa$-many copies of $\mathbb R^2$. What's left is to determine $\kappa$. But again we just need to use Alexander duality, because $H^0(M') \cong \prod_{\kappa+1} \mathbb Z$, and this is isomorphic to $\prod_{\kappa'+1} \mathbb Z$ iff there's a bijection $\kappa \to \kappa'$.

So $M$ is determined by something even coarser than the homeomorphism type of $A$: all one needs is the 0th and 1st Cech homologies $\check H_*(A)$.

Comment: you work hard and proof it for me, i have to say tnx mr Miller.