# Are $A^c$ and $B^c$ homeomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Assume that $A,B \subset R^2$ and $A,B$ are compact and connected. And $A,B$ are homeomorphic. are$A^c$ and $B^c$ homeomorphic ?

I don't have a good idea to solve that.

Comment: More interesting: if $A$ and $B$ are compact, connected and homeomorphic. Are the complementary sets homeomorphic?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Think of a set $A$ which is connected, but not simply connected, i. e. it has "holes", for example think of the unit circle $A = S^1 \subseteq \mathbf R^2$. Then $A^c$ is not connected.

Comment: Could you please explain more? Why $A$ can not be simply connected?

Comment: Added something. If only one of $A$, $B$ is simply connected, $A^c$ and $B^c$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: What if $A$ and $B$ be homeomorphic ? I think this is a better question.

Comment: Then it is a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354119/are-the-complements-of-two-homeomorphic-compact-connected-subsets-of-mathbbr