# Is the "Runge hull" of an open set open?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, connectedness

Let $X\subset\mathbb{C}$. The ''*Runge hull*'' $h(X)$ of $X$ is defined to be the the union of $X$ and all the precompact connected components of $\mathbb{C}\setminus X$.

> If $X$ is open, is $h(X)$ necessarily open?

Alternatively, this can be stated as follows. Is the union of all unbounded connected components of a closed set in $\mathbb{C}$ closed? The set $\mathbb{C}$ may also be replaced by an arbitrary manifold.

The terminology comes from *Lectures in Riemann Surfaces* by O. Forster, although he did not call it explicitly call it the ''Runge hull''. (Also, I noticed that this is not the standard definition, hence the quotation marks.) In the book, it was shown that if $X$ is closed or compact, so is $h(X)$. However, the author did not say anything about the openness of $h(X)$. After thinking for a while, I could netiher give a proof nor construct a counterexample.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; this is true more generally for any locally compact Hausdorff space.  It follows easily from the following lemma.

> **Lemma**: Let $Y$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, let $C\subseteq Y$ be a connected component which is compact, and let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $C$.  Then there is a clopen set $V\subseteq Y$ such that $C\subseteq V\subseteq U$.
>
> *Proof*: Since $C$ is compact and $Y$ is locally compact, $U$ contains a precompact neighborhood of $C$, so we may assume $U$ is precompact.  Now since $\overline{U}$ is compact Hausdorff, $C$ is not just a component of $\overline{U}$ but a quasicomponent.  Thus $C$ can be separated from each point of $\overline{U}\setminus U$ by clopen sets of $\overline{U}$, and by compactness of $\overline{U}\setminus U$ there is then a single clopen set $V$ of $\overline{U}$ such that $C\subseteq V\subseteq U$.  Then $V$ is closed in $Y$ since $\overline{U}$ is closed in $Y$, and $V$ is open in $Y$ since it is open in $U$ and $U$ is open in $Y$.  Thus $V$ is clopen in $Y$ and is the desired set.

Now if $Z$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and $X\subseteq Z$ is an open subset, let $Y=Z\setminus X$.  If $C$ is a compact connected component of $Y$, then the lemma gives a precompact clopen set $V\subseteq Y$ containing $C$.  Then $V$ is a union of compact connected components of $Y$, and it follows that the union $W$ of all compact connected components of $Y$ is open in $Y$.  It follows that $W\cup X$ is open in $Z$, and $W\cup X$ is exactly the Runge hull of $X$.

Comment: A question: A connected component in a compact Hausdorff space is a quasicomponent. Why is this true?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/11423/86856

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The proof below is incorrect; see the comments below.

I claim that the union of all unbounded connected components of a closed set $C\subset\mathbb{C}$ is closed. Consider the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$. Then $C\cup\{\infty\}$ is closed in the topology of $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$. The unbounded components of $C$ are precisely those which lie in the connected component of $\{\infty\}$ in $C\cup\{\infty\}$. Since connected components are always closed, we conclude that the union of unbounded connected components of $C$ together with $\{\infty\}$ is closed in $C\cup\{\infty\}$. Hence the union of unbounded connected components of $C$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}$.

The exact same argument works with $\mathbb{C}$ replaced by any manifold (or indeed any locally compact space, although I'm not so sure about this).

Comment: The claim that the unbounded components of $C$ are those which lie in the connected component of $\infty$ seems nontrivial.  How do you know that some subsets of $C$ which contain bounded components don't somehow become connected when you add $\infty$ to them?

Comment: In particular, it is possible to add a point to a totally disconnected space and make it connected (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan).  I suspect you can prove that can't happen here by some sort of compactness argument but it is not obvious.

Comment: @EricWofsey I see your point. Do you have an explicit counterexample by the way?

Comment: It follows easily from my answer that it can't happen for locally compact Hausdorff spaces.  The Knaster-Kuratowski fan I linked to above is an example of this sort of thing happening in more general spaces, though.